# Adding 3 different buttons on to a semi-transparent area

Tags: html, css, opacity

I need help to

1. How can I add two more image buttons inside the semi transparent area (`<figcaption>`) and all 3 buttons to be vertically centered and distributed equally inside the semi transparent area?
2. The button I've added seems to be semi-transparent (same as the `<figcaption>` opacity). I need the buttons to be `opacity:1;`?

This is the code:

```
<div class="container demo-2">
<ul class="grid cs-style-2">
<li>
<figure>
<gt_descA>Chair</gt_descA>
<gt_descC>$87.34</gt_descC>
<img src="imagez/designs/thumbs/0/01.jpg" alt="img02">
<figcaption>
<a href="index.html" onClick=""><span class="hint  hint--top  hint--rounded" data-hint="Zoom Image"><img src="additional/buttons/bu_zoom.jpg"></img></span></a>
</figcaption>
</figure>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.grid {
    padding: 70px 20px 100px 20px;
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.grid li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 234px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
}

.grid figure {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.grid figure img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.grid figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #000;
    color: #ed4e6e;
    opacity:0;
}

/*button*/
.grid figcaption a {
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Caption Style*/
.cs-style-2 figure figcaption {
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s;
    transition: transform 0.4s;
}

.no-touch .cs-style-2 figure:hover figcaption,
.cs-style-2 figure.cs-hover figcaption {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity:0.6;
}

.cs-style-2 figcaption {
    height: 24px;
    width: 187px;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.cs-style-2 figcaption a {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 31.5em) {
    .grid {
        padding: 10px 10px 100px 10px;
    }
    .grid li {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 234px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add buttons, and to align them use

```
container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Or this:

```
container {
  max-width: someval;
  margin: 0 auto; // no vertical, auto horizontal
}
```

And the alpha filter (opacity) is added to child elements too! Try to setting value for them too; seperately..